# Troubles stopping my loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, automation

```
Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""

   ....

    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Right. It works fine with numbers and stop perfectly. But With Text. It does not stop.

Ideally I want to stop at the last row of my content rather than my last row in Excel. I manage to make it work fine with numbers, but I cannot fix it with Text.

Any help would be great as I am a beginner in VBA.

```
Sub checkRoutine()
Dim i As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long

i = 1


Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
    If IsNumeric(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value & " " & Cells(7, 5).Value

    If Not IsNumeric(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
        LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
        ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow, "A").Value = Cells(i, 1).Value & " " & Cells(7, 5).Value
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see how it is the same question as the thread provided. I want to stop my loop. Not to find the last row.

Comment: I have reopened but, consider finding the last row and using a for loop instead.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep trying. In my main code of this I do have code to find the last row. It works fine with numbers, but not text.  I will try and figure out the for loop for replacing "Do While" issue.

Comment: I agree with @ScottCraner - you would be better off with a `For` loop instead.  However, to keep it like you have it, perhaps add `Len(Cells(i,1).Value) > 1` to make sure there's data.

Comment: Thanks BruceWayne, I'll try slowly debugging it and look into your suggestion too. Some strange reason my code reads blank cells and loops constantly which makes Excel crash.

Comment: we need to see more of your loop to be able to explain the phenomenon.  what you have provided should not mater if they are numbers or text.

Comment: Change to `Do While Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1))` and qualify the parent worksheet of `Cell`.

Comment: Are you sure that the `i = i + 1` is outside the `If` statement that you have shown the end of?  And are you sure that `i` isn't being changed inside the loop - other than with the `i = i + 1`?  It might be best if you post a MCVE so that we can try and reproduce it.

Comment: Also are you sure that excel is just not processing the and the loops, It may take some time to finish if there are a lot of rows or you are doing a lot in each iteration.  During this time Excel will become unresponsive.  Sometimes you may need to just wait and see.

Comment: I have updated my code with the content inside. I am still working on for loop. I will look at all your suggestions, please bare with me. I am looking at documentation too

Comment: If you are going to continually expand the number of values in column A then **yes** you are going to crash. All it takes is one text value and you will keep writing values into column A until you either reach the end of the worklsheet or run out of room for `i` (as an integer).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I'd vote to close as unclear what you're asking, but due to the re-open, I can't.

Comment: I see, if I am correct. The loop I produced reads the new cells which explains the continuous loop after it reads A1:A10 of text, A11:20 will be the result and from then onwards, it loops and loops to make excel crash

Comment: Comintern I am required to standardised it in a particular format. Particuarly in a row and when the new user wishes to add more content, they can. I want the button or function to be easily clicked or run so it takes that content and produces the result I need. Then I can use it for automation purposes.

Comment: We are back to you first finding the last cell with data, then using a for loop instead.

Comment: Mat's Mug Within my code, I already have the last row with data. The issue is not that. It is my working with text and continuous loop that doesn't stop.   I'm currently working with for loop as suggested by experienced VBA programmers, but it is not working. So I am just debugging while I try to fix this for loop issue right now.

Comment: If you find the last value and use that as the stopping point in a `For ... Next` then it is locked in and you can add text underneath it without consequence. If you use a `Do While ...` like you are, it is re-evaluating for every loop and adding additional values under the existing values causes the crash.

Comment: Everyone here can *see* why your code doesn't work.  @Jeeped already pointed out why above. What to do to "fix" it depends on what you're trying to "fix". ***That*** is the part of your question that isn't clear at this point.

Comment: FYI when you want someone to be notified of a reply, use `@TheirName` to do so. Anyway declare `i` as a `Long`, not an `Integer`, and if you know which row you need to stop at then as people have been telling you, you need a `For i = start to finish` loop, where `finish` is, I guess, your `LastRow`. I'm voting to close this question as *unclear what you're asking* until you [edit] it to clarify exactly what "doesn't work" means. When you have half the VBA expertise of Stack Overflow scratching their heads, it's a sign your question isn't clear.

Comment: [See *For Loops* topic and examples on Documentation.SO](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/1873/flow-control-structures/8169/for-loop#t=201703212038409233252). Also @Jeeped ...LOL!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by so many people, you need to change to use a `For` loop:

```
Sub checkRoutine()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long

    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If IsNumeric(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
            Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value & " " & Cells(7, 5).Value
        Else
            LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
            Cells(LastRow, "A").Value = Cells(i, 1).Value & " " & Cells(7, 5).Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `LastRow` only gets evaluated once in the line `For i = 1 To LastRow`.  That means incrementing it inside the loop doesn't change the number of iterations.

Comment: @Comintern - that's right - it's evaluated at the start and "locked in".  New lines generated by the code are therefore not processed, and therefore no infinite loop.

Comment: @Comintern - for some reason the OP wants to write stuff below the existing stuff.  (To be honest, I suspect that `Cells(LastRow, "A").Value =` should be `Cells(LastRow, "B").Value =`, to line up with the `Cells(i, 2).Value =`.)  Possibly trying to sort numerics and alpha into different blocks?

Comment: YowE3K   Thank you very much. I tested it and it worked perfectly.   In my for loop, I did "For Each text In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A11") ...End If  
Next text End Sub.  But it didn't work. Luckily your use of "If and Else" and "For i = 1 To LastRow"   solved my problem.  Thank you very much again YowE3K